# Cannot Receive UTF-8 format with String in LinkedHashMap when using RestTemplate

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-rest

So I have problem with character encoding when receive data from restclient using restTemplate to send data. and this my example code:

This is my client code; I already receive data with UTF-8 encoding:

```
rest.getMessageConverters().add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String,Object>();
params.put("modelname","character without utf-8");
MyModel oldModel = rest.postForObject(MYMODEL_SERVICE_URI + "/get", params, MyModel.class);//it return perfect model with utf-8 encoded
oldModel.setContent("Tôi muốn cập nhật model này với định dạng UTF-8");

MyModelWrapper wrapper = new MyModelWrapper();
wrapper.add(oldModel);
params.put("newmodel", wrapper);
Message message = rest.postForObject(MYMODEL_SERVICE_URI + "/update", params, Message.class);//class message contains the message back and the status of that message in boolean
System.out.println(message);
```

This is my service code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/update", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Message update(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> params){
    .....
    LinkedHashMap<String,Object> map = (LinkedHashMap<String,Object>params.get("newmodel");
    Iterator<String> iter = map.keySet().iterator();
    String key = "";
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        key = iter.next();
        System.out.println(map.get(key));//returned the string value is not in utf-8 format
        //some method casting linkedhashmap to MyModel 
    }

    ....
    return message;
}
```

And the return message of it is not in utf-8 encoding. So I need helps about encoding when receive object from rest-client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `consumes`, `produces` to `@RequestMapping` with `application/json;charset=UTF-8` and see

```
@RequestMapping(value="/update", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, but it's my fault. My code is working perfectly without add consumes, produces. I just try some other method, and still see on the console it's doesn't show utf-8 character. but when I convert the text to byte[] it's the same, so I try to use that update code and then I use get service to get that Object, and see the value is in utf-8 format. Thank for your help